# Ajax validation in Yii1: afterValidate() doesn't work if model has no errors

Tags: validation, yii, widget

I have a problem with ajax validation in Yii1. The callback method `afterValidate()` doesn't work if the model has no errors.

Here is my code:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget(
                'bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',
                array(
                    'id'=> 'add_module',
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                    'enableClientValidation' => false,
                    'clientOptions' => array(
                        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                        'afterValidate' => 'js: function(form, data, hasError) {
                            alert(hasError);
                        }'
                    ),
                    'layout' => TbHtml::FORM_LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL,
                ));
```

So `alert(hasError);` doesn't start if model has no errors. What should I do?
Action:

```
$model = ModulesInfo::model()->with('rightsInfo')->findbypk($id);
    $RI_model = RightsInfo::model()->findAll('module_id=' . $id);
    $status = true;
    $model_numeration = new ModuleNumeration;

    if (Yii::app()->request->getQuery('ModuleNumeration')) {
        $model_numeration->scenario = 'search';
        $model_numeration->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('ModuleNumeration');
        $status = false;
    }
    $controllers = $model_numeration->getControllerFromModule($model->url_name);
    $moduleNumeration  =  Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration');
    if (isset($_POST['ModulesInfo']) && $moduleNumeration ) {
        $model->name = $_POST['ModulesInfo']['name'];
        $model->icon = $_POST['ModulesInfo']['icon'];
        $model->url_name = $_POST['ModulesInfo']['url_name'];

        $model->save();

        //check if select controller, if yes validate model ModuleNumeration
        if (Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration') &&
            Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration')['controller_id'] != false
        ) {

            $model_numeration->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration');
            $model_numeration->module_id = $model->id;
            $model_numeration->scenario = 'update';
            //ajax validation odel ModuleNumeration
            if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='add_module' ){
                $model_numeration->validate();
                echo TbActiveForm::validate($model_numeration);
                Yii::app()->end();

            }

            if ($model_numeration->validate() && $model_numeration->save()) {
                $status = true;
            } else {
                $status = false;
            }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['RightsInfo']) && is_array($_POST['NewRightsInfo'])) {
            foreach ($_POST['RightsInfo'] as $exist_r_id => $exist_r) {
                if ($exist_r['code'] == '') {
                    RightsInfo::model()->deleteByPk($exist_r_id);
                } else {
                    $exist_r_model = RightsInfo::model()->findbypk($exist_r_id);
                    $exist_r_model->code = $exist_r['code'];
                    $exist_r_model->name = $exist_r['name'];
                    $exist_r_model->save();
                }
            }
        }
        if (isset($_POST['NewRightsInfo']) && is_array($_POST['NewRightsInfo']) && !empty($_POST['NewRightsInfo'])) {
            foreach ($_POST['NewRightsInfo'] as $right) {
                if ($right['code'] != "") {
                    $RI_model = new RightsInfo;
                    $RI_model->name = $right['name'];
                    $RI_model->code = $right['code'];
                    $RI_model->module_id = $id;
                    $RI_model->save();
                }
            }
        }

        ModuleNumeration::setFlashMessage($status);


    }

    $this->render('addmodule', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'RI_model' => $RI_model,
        'controllers' => $controllers,
        'model_numeration' => $model_numeration
    ));
```

Server response when there are error is:

```
 {"ModuleNumeration_action_id":["Action name cannot be blank."],"ModuleNumeration_code":["Code cannot be blank."]}
```

When there are no validation error - html page but form not submited

I found the reason why it's not working. In the form I have 3 model, one of them I need validate via ajax. There are 3 attributes in this model which are required, **BUT** in simple server validation I begin validate this model **ONLY** when first attribute was selected, if no - all model doesn't need save and validate. I did in with simple checking:

```
  if(Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration')['controller_id'] !='')
```

And it works fine.But when I tried add this checking in ajax validation:

```
     if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='add_module'    ){
        if(Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration')['controller_id'] !=''){
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model_numeration);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
```

It's not work.

Comment: Show please server response on validate query and controller's action.

Comment: What is a server response when no errors?

Comment: When there are no validation error  response server is html page but form not submited

Comment: When browser send validation query via AJAX it should return `[]` (empty array) on no errors.

Comment: Also I've noticed that you always save `$model`, even if you just run AJAX validation. You should do any validation before save.

Comment: If I delete ckecking Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration')['controller_id'] !='' in ajax validation - I see validation error. BUT I need it validate only if I check controller_id attribute.

Comment: You can ask your question with full code examples on yiiframework.ru and we can discuss more in depth. Cause I think answer would be more complex.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34993